# Método sendo chamado várias vezes

Tags: java, android

estou com um probleminha.O método de adicionar Mensagem está sendo chamada várias vezes e fica adicionando mensagens até que o app seja fechado.Não tenho idéia do que tá causando isso,vou colocar as partes de envio,se alguêm souber como ajudar,agradeço!

Fragment que contém o botão Enviar:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedinstance)
{
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat_layout,null);


    Button EnviarMensagem = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.ButtonEnviarMensagem);
    EnviarMensagem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText msg = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.EditTextMensagem);
            try {
                Controle_Chat.AdicionarMensagem(msg.getText().toString());
                Log.i("FragmentChat","Clicou em enviar mensagem");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            msg.setText("");
        }
    });
```

Controle_Chat:

```
  public static void AdicionarMensagem(String mensagem) throws IOException {


    Log.i("AdicionarMensagem","Entrou metodo Adicionar Mensagem");
    if (activity.cliente != null) {
        activity.cliente.EnviarOpcao(String.valueOf("chat:"+mensagem));
    } else {
        activity.servidor.EnviarCliente(String.valueOf("chat:"+mensagem));

    }

    mensagens.add(mensagem);


    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            FragmentChat.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
```

Controle do socket,quando o cliente recebe mensagem:

```
  BufferedReader ler = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(servidor.getInputStream()));
        String opcao;

        while((opcao=ler.readLine()) !=null)
        {
Log.i("OPCAO CLIENTE",opcao);

            if(opcao.equals("99"))
            {

                activity.ResetarJogo();
            }else if(opcao.contains("chat")){

                String[] cortada = opcao.split(":");
                Controle_Chat.AdicionarMensagem(cortada[1]);
                Log.i("Cliente","Entrou no if se tem mensagem");
            }else{
                activity.controle_jogo.SelecionarRemoto(Integer.valueOf(opcao));
                activity.controle_jogo.SetMinhaVez(true);
            }



        }
```

o Método só está nesses lugares,quando recebe mensagem ou quando envia.

A saída do console:

[image: Saída]

Alguém pode dar uma idéia do que pode estar havendo ? Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

pelo que vi, você usa a verificação `activity.cliente != null`para poder enviar as mensagens, mas não vi você voltar para `activity.cliente = null` após enviar e assim finalizar o loop.

espero que ajude.

Comment: Oi,obrigado pela ajuda,resolvi o problema de outra forma,pois não poderia setar null para a variável cliente
Tive que criar um método para Enviar e chamar este método no clicklistener do botão,colocando esse if/else dentro de outro método,parou de enviar várias vezes,agora o por quê já não sei haha.Abraços!